# Streaming large static files using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, stream, large-files, node-streams, nodejs-stream

I need to consume large unformatted read-only text files periodically and check for the presence of certain content/words in each of those files. This file is composed of all alphanumeric characters. However, I am having issues even reading to the `end` of the stream for one of these large static files.

Below is a copy of the simplest code I tried to run after noticing it was not reaching the `end` and this still does not trigger an `end` event. I can see many iterations/chunks of `data` being read, but never all of the data for the file and `end` is never triggered.

```
function readFile(file) {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file, {
      fd: null,
      flags: 'r',
      encoding: 'utf-8',
      allowVolatile: true,
      highWaterMark: staticHighWaterMark,
    });

    readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log('DATA chunk', chunk.length);
    });

    readStream.on('end', () => {
      console.log('END file');
    }); 
}
```

This is so simple that I'm starting to wonder if it's something with my environment, but if there is anything identified as an issue in the simple logic above to read the stream, please let me know.

NOTE: If I keep increasing the `highWaterMark` option it makes it further through the file, but still does not reach the `end` of the file. However, that shouldn't make a difference to reaching, or not reaching, the end of the file but instead control how much data it reads per 'chunk'.

Comment: Out of curiosity. Do you want to read it line by line?

Comment: It doesn't have to be that way, but I guess it could be, which is supported by the nodejs api today. Do you think that would make a difference for being able to reach the `end` of the file?

Comment: I'd just suggest you to use `readline` instead (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/readline.html). I'm curious about your problem. I'm going to post a code for you to test, ok?

Comment: Are you sure your environment is not cutting off the output after a certain number of lines? I know intellij IDEA will not show output after a certain number of lines have been output. What you can do to test this is to pipe the stream to a writable (file) stream and see if everything is written out. I see no reason why it shouldn't. Also, just taking a look at the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options), there is no `allowVolatile` option

Answer (score 0):

Can you test this and see if with this you will be able to read the entire file?

```
function readFileV2(file) {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file, {
      fd: null,
      flags: 'r',
      encoding: 'utf-8',
      allowVolatile: true,
      highWaterMark: staticHighWaterMark,
    });

    readStream.pipe(process.stdout);
}
```